# Angular Mat dialog closes and moves to top left of page in IE

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, modal-dialog

I have a confirmation modal pop up that is shown when a user selects a submit button.

When the modal appears, the user has the option to click on a button to close the modal. Here's how it looks like:

HTML:

```
<ng-template #confirmModal>
  <custom-modal-body-component 
    (cancelFn)="closeModal()"
  </custom-modal-body-component>
</ng-template>
```

TS:

```
  @ViewChild('confirmModal', { static: true }) confirmModalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private modalService: MatDialog,
  ) {}

  submit() {
    this.myModal = this.modalService.open(this.confirmModalTemplate);
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.myModal.close();
  }
```

My issue is, that when the user closes the modal it moves to the top left corner of the page for a brief moment before closing. I do not want this to happen.

I'd like the modal to just close normally without jumping to the top left corner of the page.  We've recently upgraded Angular/material from 7.x.x to 8.2.1. This issue did not appear in version 7 and we do not want to downgrade to 7. Any thoughts on what could be going on?

This only happens in IE, which we need to support.

EDIT:
It should be noted that this behaviour is only occurring on two particular pages of our application. We open modals in the same way across all pages, but this issue does not persist on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with going out of zone. Try putting the close and open of the model inside the zone like so:

```
    constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

    const dialogRef1 = this.zone.run(() => {
        this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {});
    });
```

Comment: This solution did change the modals behaviour of jumping to the top left of the screen, although it did scratch an item off my list of potential causes.